# Can 面子 mean "face" as in the physical face?

Tags: meaning, words

I have read the meanings for 面子 but I would like to know if maybe it can also mean 顔, the physical face maybe used as a slang.
For example, 「ヒデェ面子だ」can only mean "awful people (members)?"
[On this website with synonyms it says](https://thesaurus.weblio.jp/content/%E9%9D%A2%E5%AD%90) 「外から見たものの様子のこと」and there are synonyms like 外見, 姿, 容貌.
It cannot be used to refer to the physical face at all?

Answer (score 2):

No, it cannot mean/indicate physical face, as far as I aware.

That synonyms are really just for "外から見たものの様子のこと", and that's also why there's "メンツ・面子" is in that synonyms list (Also in 世間の風評, 会合や事業などに参加する人々のこと.)

The only real synonyms I can think of for 面子 is "面目" and "体面" for "save/lose face", "prestige", and "顔触れ" for members.

Comment: I see...So it cannot be used to refer to the physical face. I thought that it was possible because of what I have seen in the manga that I read. There was a group but some manga panels focused on one person, who was being stared at by another person. The friend of the person who was staring made that comment ヒデェ面子だ so I was like "Is he talking about the group or that particular person? I mean why were those panels focused on one person?" And that's why I thought it meant "face".

Comment: @AliceB.Rabbit 面子 in ヒデェ面子だ refers to the whole "lineup" (of a team/group), not individual appearances or personalities. The sentence means they are useless as a whole (even if some of the members may be decent if seen individually).

Comment: @AliceB.Rabbit I don't know for sure but maybe that person is like a leader of that group? Or the author was just lazy to write all of members...?

Comment: @skye-at Thank you for the help. So, the word isn't slang for the physical face...

Comment: @naruto Thank you! It would seem that the word can't be used to say "face"...I asked because of those synonyms I found on that website which I linked in my post. The character in the manga I read speaks colloquially, so I thought it was a possibility that it could have meant something like "ugly mug" for example.